# Invalid Syntax error in URLS.py in DJango

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-3.6, django-urls, django-2.0

Getting following error in my urls.py

```
Django/Projects/first_project/simple_app/urls.py", line 7
    re_path(re'^details/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.details),
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

urls.py is as follows :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

   re_path(re'^details/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.details),
   path('', views.index)

]
```

Comment: It should be `r'..'` not `re'..'`.

Answer (score 1):

You defined a string with a `re'..'` prefix. But Python does not have a `re'..'` prefix.

It has an `r'..'` prefix, and this does *not* mean "regex", but *"raw*". It does *not* mean you construct a regex, but more that if you write for example `r'foo\nbar'`, you did *not* write a *new line* character (`'\n'`), but you write a backslash `r'\'` (or `'\\'` for a regular string) followed by a `'n'` character. This is necessary, since if you construct a regex, the backslashes should still be individual characters.

You can thus rewrite it to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # r instead of re
    re_path(r'^details/(?P\d+)/$', views.details),
    path('', views.index)
]
```

Python also has `f'..'` strings (that can contain variables that are then formatted), and `b'..'` strings (for binary strings), but those do not really matter in the case of `urlpatterns`.

You thus do not *per se* need to use the `r'..'` prefix at all. But in that case, you have to ensure that you escape backslashes yourself. This makes it harder to write and read. Therefore `r'..'` is probably the best way to write regexes.